# "Error Code 701": Hosted Feature Service from ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service

I got this error message when trying to view item details of a hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online. Along with this error message, the layer in question could not be loaded to the web map nor was visible on the Collector App.

Has anyone else experienced random outages where layers could not be loaded to an AGOL web map/on Collector?

Error:

> The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please
>   try again. Error code 701. A severe error occurred on the current
>   command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

ESRI technical support (UK) can't seem to put their finger on the issue, and it is causing a great deal of pain!

Comment: 1. Can you please copy the text of the error into your question so that it is searchable? A screenshot is not.  2. Is this consistent? Does it only happen with certain devices? Are you able to submit data through collector and you receive this error when you are trying to view from another device? A little more detail would be helpful.

Comment: The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 701. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

No data can be submitted using a device because the feature layer(s) are not visible. The sharing properties of the layers are correct because data has been submitted previously. The disappearing of the feature layer appears to be random, and is not linked to mobile internet connectivity.

This issue is also replicated on AGOL. The layer cannot be added to the map.